# ESP8266 engine PWM - problem on startup

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, esp8266

I have a circuit like one on scheme. I would like to drive 12V/3A DC motor with PWM from ESP8266 pin output. Circuit works just fine (FET is only little bit heating), but on ESP startup, engine turns on (for less then a second), probably until the pin is initialized with full value (1023 = 3.3 V - this makes engine off). I am looking for a circuit modification which would keep motor off during ESP startup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3oef1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you have a pullup on the ESP8266 output?

Comment: Which pin are you using? There are internall pullups for some pins. However, GPIO 0, 2, and 15 are typically reserved for special functions and are limited in capability.

Comment: use GPIO 4 and 5, which are low from reset, through boot, and until activated; other inputs can screw up boot order or go haywire with floating and unexpected voltages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making the input positive logic? When ESP8266 starts up, IO is set as input according to [this website](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations). In the circuit below, if input is floating then the motor is off.

Plus, PWM duty-cycle would be "right-side up". 100% PWM = fully on, whereas in your original circuit, 100% PWM = fully off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu2Rn8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this works wery well. Just let me an additional question: Since R1 and R2 forms voltage divider, for IRF540N, is 6V einough for full saturation and 3A current flow for motor?

Comment: Datasheet shows 4.5V Vgs is enough for 10 Amps at 12V at room temp. I thought I saw one datasheet say 15V abs max Vgs so 12V close. On second look I see 20V abs max Vgs. You can adjust the values of R1 and R2 as you see fit. If you want to make it really robust, you can add a zener diode to clamp Vgs to 12V or whatever. It's the most sensitive part of the circuit and a zener would help prevent glitches on 12V supply from damaging the gate. Auto 12V can be very glitchy.

Answer (score 1):

Put a pull up resistor (~10K) from the base of Q1 to the 3V3 of your CPU. The CPU output is probably low or floating during reset & start-up.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try adding a pull-up resistor and work in inverted mode: analogWrite(pin, 100-value);